# Is Kerbal Space Program a valid place to pull illustrative videos from?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [Is Kerbal Space Program a valid reference when answering SX questions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/613/4660) and thinking about what I've pondered doing with certain questions - taking a short video of the game in order to illustrate a question or an answer. For concepts like gravity assists, escape velocity, spheres of influence, aerobraking, gravity drag, phase angles, and on and on, it seems possible to visually demonstrate the concept well that way.

Then I considered Deer Hunter's point about the level of realism in simulators, especially one as simplistic as KSP. I don't know when or where the realism of the game especially breaks down. Is there a way to distinguish where it would tend to be misleading?

Answer (score 3):

There certainly are cases in which KSP can help illustrate a concept, and for those cases, yes, a quick video is helpful. Just know the limitations first.